# Python webscraper & missing output data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to scrape reviews from a website and store them to a csv using Python (3.7) & BeautifulSoup.  It seems the scrape is successful, but when I write to the file, only one column contains full data, and the rest just the first character.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated, and sorry if it's glaringly obvious - it's a fresh hobby :)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#URL to scrape
my_url = "https://www.indeed.com/cmp/Capital-One/reviews?fcountry=ALL&lang="

#open connection, grab page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "lxml")

#grab all reviews on page
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"cmp-review-container"})
uClient.close()
#write to csv
filename = "indeedreviewtest.csv"
f=open(filename, "w")

headers = "review_id, review_score, role, review_text\n"

f.write(headers)

#loop through each review, collect review ID, rating, role & verbatum
for container in containers:
    reviewid_container = container.div["data-tn-entityid"]
    reviewid = reviewid_container[0]
    score_container = container.div.div.div.meta["content"]
    reviewscore = score_container[0]
    role_container = container.find("span", attrs={"class":"cmp-reviewer- job-title"}).text
    reviewerrole = role_container[0]
    reviewtext_container = container.find("span", attrs={"class":"cmp-review-text"}).text
    reviewtext = reviewtext_container

    f.write(reviewid + "," + reviewscore + "," + reviewerrole.replace(",", "|") + "," + reviewtext.replace(",", "|") + "\n")

f.close()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mixed up `find()` and `findAll()`.

`find()` stops when finding the first element which matches the criteria, while `findAll()` brings all of them.

By using `role_container[0]` you're getting the first character from that element text.

You can try just:

```
reviewerrole = container.find("span", attrs={"class":"cmp-reviewer-job-title"}).text
reviewtext = container.find("span", attrs={"class":"cmp-review-text"}).text
```

Besides that, consider using the `csv` module for reading/writing CSV files. More info:https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Comment: Thanks so much you wonderful man, that did the trick!

Really appreciate the further reading suggestion too, it's at the top of my to do list.